# Service started with podman not reachable from external network

Tags: docker, ubuntu, podman

I have an ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) (call it machine A), on which there are docker and podman installed.
Their versions are:

- podman: 3.4.2
- docker: 23.0.1

I have a compose file describing some prometheus instance, that I want to run either with docker or podman (not at the same time of course) and then access via the browser (port 9090) from a different machine (call it machine B).
The service is assigned to an externally created network test:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
1af699f798cd   bridge    bridge    local
47abbcc1fb96   host      host      local
bd34621bee08   none      null      local
1540ec6b02de   test      bridge    local
```

```
 podman network ls
NETWORK ID    NAME        VERSION     PLUGINS
2f259bab93aa  podman      0.4.0       bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning
7867d86a50ef  test        0.4.0       bridge,portmap,firewall,tuning,dnsname
```

Doing this with docker on machine A works just fine and I can access prometheus via the browser from machine B.
Netstat on machine A shows me that the ports are listening and everything seems fine:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      420189/docker-proxy
...
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      420196/docker-proxy
...
```

However, if I try to do the same thing via podman from machine A again, the page is not reachable from machine B.
Netstat on machine A shows me, that the port would be listening again:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      444958/containers-r
...
```

Via the following In confirmed it being the prometheus server:

```
 sudo ps -ef | grep -E "444958|444523|443277"
abc       443277  419940  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/podman-compose up prometheus
abc       444523  443277  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 podman start -a prometheus
abc       444524  443277  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 sed -e s/^/?[1;34m[prometheus] |?[0m\ /;
abc       444676  444523  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/slirp4netns --disable-host-loopback --mtu=65520 --enable-sandbox --enable-seccomp -c -r 3 --netns-type=path /run/user/1001/netns/rootless-cni-ns tap0
abc       444958  444523  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 containers-rootlessport
abc       444963  444958  0 14:16 pts/0    00:00:00 containers-rootlessport-child
abc       445067  420369  0 14:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -E 444958|444523|443277
```

On https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/basic_networking.md I read, that it is not possible to reach this container from outside if started rootlessly.
So I also tried it using sudo, but the result was basically the same:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      454803/conmon
...
```

```
sudo ps -ef | grep 454803
root      454803       1  0 14:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/podman/conmon --api-version 1 -c 2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922 -u 2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922 -r /usr/bin/crun -b /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922/userdata -p /run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922/userdata/pidfile -n prometheus --exit-dir /run/libpod/exits --full-attach -s -l journald --log-level warning --runtime-arg --log-format=json --runtime-arg --log --runtime-arg=/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922/userdata/oci-log --conmon-pidfile /run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922/userdata/conmon.pid --exit-command /usr/bin/podman --exit-command-arg --root --exit-command-arg /var/lib/containers/storage --exit-command-arg --runroot --exit-command-arg /run/containers/storage --exit-command-arg --log-level --exit-command-arg warning --exit-command-arg --cgroup-manager --exit-command-arg systemd --exit-command-arg --tmpdir --exit-command-arg /run/libpod --exit-command-arg --runtime --exit-command-arg crun --exit-command-arg --storage-driver --exit-command-arg overlay --exit-command-arg --storage-opt --exit-command-arg overlay.mountopt=nodev,metacopy=on --exit-command-arg --events-backend --exit-command-arg journald --exit-command-arg container --exit-command-arg cleanup --exit-command-arg 2f60ecafd8cb76e41e5abb958e662f33c348608bedf9f5406687104e834f9922
nobody    454806  454803  0 14:21 ?        00:00:00 /bin/prometheus --config.file=/app.cfg/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/app.cfg/prometheus_data --web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries --web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles
```

From machine A I also confirmed that the service is running by simply doing a `curl localhost:9090`, both, when using docker and when using podman and they showed the same result.

As with docker I was using the same ports and everything, I probably can exclude some firewall issues.

Can someone maybe give me some pointers as to why the service might not be reachable if I start it with podman?
Please let me know if you need any further information from me and I'll provide it as soon as possible.

Thank you.